# Why do I get a 'Local variable 'length' might be referenced before assignment' warning here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

```
def lds(s):
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        if s[::-1][0:i] == s[::-1][i:2 * i]:
            length = i
        else:
            length = 0
    return length
```

This code should give the length of the longest double suffix of a string.

Comment: Try to define 'length = 0' before your for loop

Comment: what happens if the string is empty / has length 0?

Comment: @ThisIsMatin That works indeed! Thank you. But do you know why my previous code didn't work?

Comment: Ask yourself the question in @luk2302 's comment. That is why.

Comment: Because length can be zero and it would not loop through the for loop, therefore returning variable that is not defined.